# How to pause MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, audio

I am trying to use a single button to play and pause MediaPlayer. But cannot get it to work. It stops the sound and restarts from the beginning. I tried tweaking the pause code a little but only ended up making it worse by causing the sound to start a new one on top of the current creating a terrible echo effect.

```
private var mp: MediaPlayer? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

val button1 = this.bOne
val button2 - this.bTwo

button1.setOnClickListener {

    onPause()
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this@MovieActivity, R.raw.soundOne)
    mediaPlay()
  }

button2.setOnClickListener {

    onPause()
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this@MovieActivity, R.raw.soundTwo)
    mediaPlay()
  }
}

private fun mediaPlay() {
    if (mp!!.isPlaying) {
        mp!!.pause()
    } else {
        mp!!.start()
    }
    mp!!.isLooping = true
}

override fun onPause() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp!!.pause()
    }
    super.onPause()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling onPause from button clicks...onPause is related to activity life cycle and in your case I think you shouldn't call it from button click event.

Comment: Because otherwise with each button click a new instance of the sound starts to play creating an echo mess. Also if the user presses another button, it plays that sounds on top of all subsequent sounds as well. I’d like to be able to freely pause and play the sounds without having to create separate play and pause buttons This way the user can control the sounds playing over each other. I’m sure there is a better way to do it, but I’m a total neophyte when it comes to Android.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of media player every time you click the button ... that is why two sounds play at the same time. Initialize media player object one time only in onCreate method and remove onPause.

Comment: OK, so now each instance is unique and not just mp being used for all. Works great, thank you! Unfortunately I have a new side effect when I leave the activity. Sound continues to play and when I navigate to the activity containing the sound buttons and press them again the pause no longer works. How can I kill the audio process when I leave the activity?

Comment: You have to stop and release the mediaplayer whenever you leave the activity..  you can do so by overriding onDestroy method if you finish it or from onPause method if you keep the activity in your back stack.